# how to get the § symbol on pc minecraft 1.13.3 querty keyboard

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

i already know how to do THIS you just do the unicode alt+0167, but how do you get it in minecraft. if you cant. i ask how to get the font attribute to it. (this is **minecraft java**)

Comment: Any particular reason you unaccepted my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes

-To enter "§" on Windows with most US/UK English keyboards type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NUMPAD2</kbd>+<kbd>NUMPAD1</kbd> (alt code on cp437). For any other keyboard, the Windows ANSI version <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NUMPAD0</kbd>+<kbd>NUMPAD1</kbd>+<kbd>NUMPAD6</kbd>+<kbd>NUMPAD7</kbd> often works. If EnableHexNumpad is enabled in the Windows registry, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NUMPAD+</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>NUMPAD7</kbd> (using the main keyboard for "A") works for any language due to it being Unicode.

-On a Mac with a US keyboard, type <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> (or <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> for US Extended). For any other keyboard, type <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>+<kbd>00a7</kbd>.

-On Linux with the compose key activated, type <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>. The symbol can also be typed by using Unicode shortcuts: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u00a7</kbd>.

When part of JSON text, the symbol can be written as \u00A7 or \u00a7.

Alternatively in Bedrock Edition, the character can be copied from this page (§), and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (macOS) can be pressed to paste the character into a book. Note that pasting does not work on everything (e.g. chat, command blocks, world names).

In early Java Edition Classic versions, the character used was & instead of §.[2]